# OCaml - Getting hints about what the _Syntax error_ is

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I'm starting to do write some OCaml but I find finding Syntax errors quite hard. I come from JavaScript where it would tell me `Unexpected token ***`. But here, all I get is `Syntax error`...

Is there some way to get a more explicit message?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw in your reply to ygrek's helpful answer that your code is http://pastebin.com/6c0sKFeh.

This code uses a syntax extension to support stream parsers, a form of syntactic sugar that was removed from the core languages quite a few years ago. To compile it as is, you should add a preprocessor invocation command to your compilation line. Instead of:

```
ocamlc -o foo ... foo.ml
```

use

```
ocamlc -pp camlp4o -o foo ... foo.ml
```

The reason why `camlp4o` "just returns the source code" is that it parsed it correctly, and now prints out the postprocessed source. You can also store this source in a file `camlp4o foo.ml -o foo2.ml`, and then compile it directly: `ocamlc ... foo2.ml`.

If your teaching material did not inform you that the processor should be used, it is out of date. This is one of the few problems with the book "Developping Applications with Objective Caml", for example -- which is otherwise a great resource that I do recommend reading.

PS: next time, please post your source code right away.

Answer (score 3):

Try `camlp4o source.ml`, it will parse code with different parser that is able to tell what it expects at each point of input.

Comment: It did help me find what one error was coming from. But now I still have a syntax error and this time, ocamlp4o just returns the source code :( http://pastebin.com/6c0sKFeh

Comment: @xavierm02 If `camlp4o` outputs source code and no error message, that means there was no syntax error in the file. So why did `ocamlc` produce an error? Because you're using the `parser` keyword which doesn't actually exist in ocaml - the compiler interprets it as the name of a function and then chokes on the following `|` because there's no reason for a `|` to be there. The reason that `camlp4o` does not produce the same error is that `parser` is an extension provided by `camlp4`, so you actually need to use `camlp4` if you want to use the `parser` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Can you copy paste the whole error message? It most probably contains a very precise location: filename, line number, column number. And the correction needs to be made right there.

Sometimes this location is the end of a block, and the correction needs to be made inside the block.

Also, if you can boil down your code to a minimal example, it will be easier to help.

Comment: I don't think the question was how to fix the specific syntax error the OP is currently encountering (in fact I'm not sure that the OP is even encountering a syntax error at this moment - at least the question didn't say so). The question is how to get clearer syntax error messages in general.

Comment: I actually had a problem but I also know I will have many more so I prefer learning to fix them myself whenever possible :)